# Zendesk - How to detect if I Change (before submit) Requester Name in opened Tickets?

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I have a server side app, which display customer info such as name, id, email etc based on currently opened ticket.
My next task is to update the Requester name in Zendesk App ( server side app ) if i made changes in Ticket Requester before submit.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom events using `client.on('event_type', handler)`. Refer to [ZAF Client API](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/apps/apps-core-api/client_api/#clientonname-handler-context) for available events depending on the location.

Here is an example:

```
if (client) {
    client.on('ticket.requester.name.changed', function(e) {
        document.getElementById('requesterNameElementId').innerText = e;
    });
} else {
    console.log('ZAF Client only works within Zendesk iFrame');
}
```